# Extension: Adding a contact tab

Tags: drupal, extension

I am new in CiviCRM. I am learning extension development and want to know documents/resources about how to create a contact tab showing certain information via API like Campaign Pages.

I am on Drupal 7 along with CiviCRM 4.7

Thanks